# "making noise" or "make a noise"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, idiomatic-language

I was beginning to get confused on this sentence structure. I wager ***a noise*** is not singular or is it?

> Stop making a noise
>   Stop making noise

Which of these is a good way to present this situation?

Comment: More context is needed to make a proper choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"noise" is both countable and uncountable. It's countable when it means one specific sound. "I heard a strange noise." It's uncountable when it's noise in general. "I heard some noise coming from the shop."

Answer (score 5):

While you could say "Stop making a noise" for a single occurrance, its more natural to say what the noise is, also stop is not good here, because it implies an ongoing condition (that would be "noise" not "a noise"). Better would be:

> Don't make a sound.

*Don't make a noise* is also OK, but I think (in AmE anyway)

> Don't make *any* noise.

is better.

Answer (score 4):

"Stop making a noise" is strange because the speaker must be referring back to a specific sound, part of the context shared by the speaker and listener.  "Stop making *that* noise" would be more appropriate in reference to a specific sound.  In this sentence, *noise* is countable.

"Stop making noise" is also possible.  Here, *noise* is treated as a mass noun meaning "noise in general".  The focus is not on the specific sound the listener is or was making.

Answer (score 2):

The word *noise* is countable and uncountable both. So, it depends on the context.

OLD in its *similar example* **prefers** putting the indefinite article *a*.

> [noise (n)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/noise) - don't make a noise

You may further read on this on the same page to learn where is it countable and where is it not.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when someone is making noise, it is more common in speech to say 'making noise,' not 'making a noise,' because the person is usually making more than one noise. Since you want the person to stop, it means that the noise is ongoing, so it will have various different sounds. 'Making a noise' is appropriate, but 'making noise' just sounds more normal.

Comment: If I run a leafblower so that the noise is continuous, would you tell me to stop _making __a__ noise_, or _making noise_?

Comment: making noise, because the leafblower will probably make different noises as it hits different things, and the fan isn't in the same position every time

Comment: But then, let's say I place it in an orientation such that it will continue running, and don't actually move it around, at all?

Answer (score 0):

**make noise**
To be very outspoken about something, especially that which one dislikes or disagrees with.

**make a noise**
to speak or act in a way designed to attract a lot of attention or publicity.